# How to exclude/remove text within an import.io field extract automatically

Tags: regex, xpath, import.io

I'm using regex within import.io to only match fields when they start with a certain string which works correctly. So for example i use the following to match items that start with 'testing testing ':
^(testing\stesting\s.+

It there any way to have it return the value excluding this string (presumably using xpath in addition to regex?) So if the field value is "testing testing 1234" then i would want it to just return "1234" without the "testing testing" at the front?

Obviously I can do this manually afterwards but want to try and find a way of doing it automatically as part of the export?

Thanks,

Dave

Comment: Why don't you use capturing-groups? Like `^testing testing (.*)` : _https://regex101.com/r/bY4dG9/2_

Comment: For some reason this doesn't work in import.io, i'm not sure why :(

Comment: In: _http://support.import.io/knowledgebase/articles/341182-xpaths-regex_ I've found this link: _http://regexlib.com/_.. Maybe it could help you

Answer (score 2):

You could use (?:\d+) this would get all the digits within a capturing group. I usually use http://regexr.com/ to build regex, it offers great cheatsheets and reference material.

Comment: Thanks for your reply Meg, unfortunately the digits were just an example, i'm actually trying to pull non numeric characters (excluding the string i specify) so your example wouldn't work but if you have any other ideas they would be greatly appreciated :) Thanks!